# SQL Structure for a unique group chat

Tags: sql, postgresql

There's `channel`, `user`, and `channel_to_user`.

Basically channel_to_user holds an is-in relationship between `user` and `channel`.

However, I need the channels to be unique in the set of their users.

For example, if channel X has users A and B, there **cannot be** a channel Y that has users A and B.

However, there can be a channel Z that has users A, B **and** C.

I thought about two solutions:

- trigger
- a column with an array of sorted user ids, which would be unique

Is there anything more elegant? I'm using `postgres`.

Comment: Can you explain why you would need that to exist? That seems like an odd condition and could lead to some interesting issues down the road...

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your table structure, some sample data would help. If you don't already have a channel identifier, how can you tell which user groups are on a given channel?

Comment: An array sounds reasonable for an unusual situation such as this one. I wouldn't consider this a gauche table row: channel (1); users {U4, U12, U15, U23}.

Answer (score 0):

A unique constraint on the column with the array of sorted users id by channel sounds good. You can create a trigger function before insert or update on that table so that to automatically order the elements of that array :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_function()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
NEW.user_id_array = SELECT array(SELECT unnest (NEW.user_id_array) AS id ORDER BY id)
RETURN NEW ;
END ;
$$ ;

CREATE TRIGGER function_trigger BEFORE INSERT OF UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION your_function() ;
```